# Terraform Subnets Wrong CIDR Addresses

Tags: terraform

Im having an issue in Terraform with subnets being generated with the wrong CIDR addresses. Before raising an issue in Github I just wanted to check whether anyone could see an error in my work.

The code to create the subnets is:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block        = "${var.public_subnets[count.index]}"
  availability_zone = "${var.azs[count.index]}"
  count             = "${length(var.public_subnets)}"

  tags {
    Name = "${var.name}-subnet-public-${element(var.azs, count.index)}"
    env       = "${var.env}"
    role      = "vpc-subnet-public"
    terraform = "true"
  }

  map_public_ip_on_launch = "${var.map_public_ip_on_launch}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-app" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block        = "${var.private_subnets_app[count.index]}"
  availability_zone = "${var.azs[count.index]}"
  count             = "${length(var.private_subnets_app)}"

  tags {
    Name = "${var.name}-subnet-private-app-${element(var.azs, count.index)}"
    env       = "${var.env}"
    role      = "vpc-subnet-private-app"
    terraform = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private-data" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block        = "${var.private_subnets_data[count.index]}"
  availability_zone = "${var.azs[count.index]}"
  count             = "${length(var.private_subnets_data)}"

  tags {
    Name = "${var.name}-subnet-private-data-${element(var.azs, count.index)}"
    env       = "${var.env}"
    role      = "vpc-subnet-private-data"
    terraform = "true"
  }
}
```

And the code using the module is:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "../modules/vpc"
  name   = "vpc-${var.env}"
  env    = "${var.env}"
  azs    = "${var.azs}"
  vpc_cidr_block  = "${var.vpc_cidr_block}"
  public_subnets       = ["10.10.0.0/20", "10.10.64.0/20", "10.10.128.0/20"]
  private_subnets_app  = ["10.10.16.0/20", "10.10.68.0/20", "10.10.132.0/20"]
  private_subnets_data = ["10.10.32.0/20", "10.10.72.0/20", "10.10.136.0/20"]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
}
```

Terraform generates a correct plan:

```
Path: development.plan

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-app.0
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1a"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.16.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "false"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-private-app-eu-west-1a"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-private-app"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-app.1
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1b"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.68.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "false"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-private-app-eu-west-1b"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-private-app"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-app.2
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1c"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.132.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "false"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-private-app-eu-west-1c"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-private-app"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-data.0
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1a"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.32.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "false"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-private-data-eu-west-1a"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-private-data"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-data.1
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1b"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.72.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "false"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-private-data-eu-west-1b"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-private-data"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-data.2
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1c"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.136.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "false"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-private-data-eu-west-1c"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-private-data"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.public.0
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1a"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.0.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "true"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-public-eu-west-1a"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-public"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.public.1
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1b"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.64.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "true"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-public-eu-west-1b"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-public"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"

+ module.vpc.aws_subnet.public.2
    availability_zone:       "eu-west-1c"
    cidr_block:              "10.10.128.0/20"
    map_public_ip_on_launch: "true"
    tags.%:                  "4"
    tags.Name:               "vpc-development-subnet-public-eu-west-1c"
    tags.env:                "development"
    tags.role:               "vpc-subnet-public"
    tags.terraform:          "true"
    vpc_id:                  "vpc-e5200781"


Plan: 9 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

But when I apply it some subnets are created with the wrong CIDR addresses so it causes conflicts. These are the logs:

```
Error applying plan:

2017/01/16 17:04:58 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
4 error(s) occurred:

* aws_subnet.public.2: Error creating subnet: InvalidSubnet.Conflict: The CIDR '10.10.128.0/20' conflicts with another subnet
    status code: 400, request id: e77f399d-1451-4fea-bffb-473386ee9398
* aws_subnet.private-app.1: Error creating subnet: InternalError: An internal error has occurred
    status code: 500, request id: c0c09a05-a00b-4eda-987d-075447b0a183
* aws_subnet.private-data.1: Error creating subnet: InternalError: An internal error has occurred
    status code: 500, request id: 6d989fc2-6dc3-4e24-a152-b2abac376046
* aws_subnet.private-data.2: Error creating subnet: InternalError: An internal error has occurred
    status code: 500, request id: ecda81f9-12be-4ea3-b883-04e5f074ca87

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

And if I do a terraform show you can see that the CIDR blocks for one of the private subnets is incorrect:

```
module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-app.0:
  id = subnet-c1210bb7
  availability_zone = eu-west-1a
  cidr_block = 10.10.16.0/20
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags.% = 4
  tags.Name = vpc-development-subnet-private-app-eu-west-1a
  tags.env = development
  tags.role = vpc-subnet-private-app
  tags.terraform = true
  vpc_id = vpc-e5200781
module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-app.2:
  id = subnet-ebf4c28f
  availability_zone = eu-west-1c
  cidr_block = 10.10.128.0/20
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags.% = 4
  tags.Name = vpc-development-subnet-private-app-eu-west-1c
  tags.env = development
  tags.role = vpc-subnet-private-app
  tags.terraform = true
  vpc_id = vpc-e5200781
module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-data.0:
  id = subnet-ce210bb8
  availability_zone = eu-west-1a
  cidr_block = 10.10.32.0/20
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags.% = 4
  tags.Name = vpc-development-subnet-private-data-eu-west-1a
  tags.env = development
  tags.role = vpc-subnet-private-data
  tags.terraform = true
  vpc_id = vpc-e5200781
module.vpc.aws_subnet.public.0:
  id = subnet-c0210bb6
  availability_zone = eu-west-1a
  cidr_block = 10.10.0.0/20
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags.% = 4
  tags.Name = vpc-development-subnet-public-eu-west-1a
  tags.env = development
  tags.role = vpc-subnet-public
  tags.terraform = true
  vpc_id = vpc-e5200781
module.vpc.aws_subnet.public.1:
  id = subnet-a596e5fd
  availability_zone = eu-west-1b
  cidr_block = 10.10.64.0/20
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags.% = 4
  tags.Name = vpc-development-subnet-public-eu-west-1b
  tags.env = development
  tags.role = vpc-subnet-public
  tags.terraform = true
  vpc_id = vpc-e5200781
```

The subnet for module.vpc.aws_subnet.private-app.2 should be 10.10.132.0/20. Im also getting 500 errors when trying to run this but I dont know if its related.

Would appreciate if anyone could confirm whether they have seen this behaviour before or whether it looks like a bug, in which case I will raise on github.

Many thanks

Comment: `10.10.132.0/20` isn't a valid CIDR range, AWS is just transforming it into the closest valid CIDR range which is `10.10.128.0/20`. A load of your other CIDR ranges are also incorrectly calculated so you're going to end up with stuff all over the place hence the collision.

Comment: yeah thanks, just realised when I tried to create it manually through the gui. teach me for just copying subnets from a page. thanks for clarifying

Comment: Also instead of calculating your cidr subnets by hand take a look at https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#cidrsubnet-iprange-newbits-netnum-